# React cancel async functions in useEffect that depends on other variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

Imagine I have a UI that has 2 controls: a date picker (which maps to a state `date`) and a drop down (which maps to a state `filter`)

I'm using `useEffect` in this React app to make an API call that uses the `date` and the `filter`. The code is set up like so:

```
const {date, filter} = state;

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const result = await makeAPICallWithDate(date, filter); // API call here
    // Update some UI state with the result
  }

  fetchData();
}, [date, filter]);
```

I have a `<` and `>` buttons that can change the `date` state pretty quickly. I notice that if I click very fast on these buttons, I get into a weird state where the whole thing is in an infinite loop and my server log shows that I'm making a bunch of API calls repeatedly.

I suspect that this is because my `async` function returns after the state has been updated. This doesn't happen if I click the `<` and `>` button slowly -- most likely because the async function has time to finish.

Questions:

1. Is my assumption correct?
2. How can I fix this so that nothing breaks when I spam the nav buttons?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to debounce call, so you'll only make a single call while clicking fast.

You can use the `debounce` function that comes with lodash, create your own (see example [here](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function)), or use a [standalone module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debounce).

```
const {date, filter} = state;

const debounceFetch = useMemo(() => debounce(async (date, filter) => {
  const result = await makeAPICallWithDate(date, filter); // API call here
  // Update some UI state with the result
}, 300), [setUIState]);

useEffect(() => {
  debounceFetch(date, filter);
}, [date, filter, debounceFetch]);
```

Answer (score 0):

On return from useEffect you have to return function which will call [AbortController](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController)

```js
const {date, filter} = state;

useEffect(() => {
  const controller = new AbortController();
  let signal = controller.signal;
  const fetchData = async () => {
    return await fetch(url, {signal})
  }

  fetchData();
  return () => {
     controller.abort();
  } 
}, [date, filter]);
```

That way when you will call again useEffect then previous one will be canceled.

Debounce is good idea as well. but on slow network problem can still occur. So in my opinion you should combine this with debounce.